# Adding mongodb driver to laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I'am trying to add mongodb driver for my laravel project, my php installed version is `7.4.26` i started by downloading the `php_mongodb.dll`   [7.4 Thread Safe (TS) x86](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/1.8.0beta1/php_mongodb-1.8.0beta1-7.4-ts-vc15-x86.zip)  from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.8.0beta1/windows) then i added the `php_mongodb.dll` into `C:/xampp/php/ext` folder and edited the `php.ini` file by adding `extension=php_mongodb.dll` after that i tried to run `composer require jenssegers/mongodb`in order to add the `MongoDB` package for my `Laravel 8` application i keep getting this error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongodb.dll'
 (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.),
 C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mongodb.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And when i try to run `php -m` command to list the php modules i can't find the `mongodb module` that i just added

Comment: Make double sure your PHP is also x86 TS and not x64 and/or NTS. Also why go for an older beta version instead of the [latest stable one](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.12.0/windows)?

Comment: that was it, it fixed my issue thank you